# Pandas Series.strids deprecated, and pandas groupby error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apriori, mlxtend

**Here are a few lines of code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori 
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

def encode_c(x):
if x <= 0:
    return 0
if x >= 1:
    return 1
return 0


def get_product_consequents():
  all_transactions_df = get_dataframe()
  basket = (all_transactions_df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c']
    .sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
    .set_index('a'))
  basket = basket.applymap(encode_c)
  frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket, min_support=0.07, use_colnames=True)
  rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", 
    min_threshold=1)
  rules['antecedants_length'] = rules['antecedents'].str.len()
  rules['consequents_length'] = rules['consequents'].str.len()
  rules = rules[(rules['lift'] >= 4) &  # 6
              (rules['confidence'] >= 0.4)]  # 0.8
  rules = rules[(rules['antecedants_length'] == 1) & 
    (rules['consequents_length'] == 1)]
  rules = (rules.groupby(['antecedants'])['consequents'])
```

**IMAGE 1**

[image: deprecated error image]

**IMAGE 2**

[image: key error image]

**When I DO:** [learning apriori from](http://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html)

```
rules["antecedant_len"] = rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

**I GET:**
IMAGE 1

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle
\pydevd_resolver.py:71:
FutureWarning: Series.strides is deprecated
and will be removed in a future version
  return getattr(var, attribute)
```

I was doing it from: [mlxtend association_rules and apriori docs](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/association_rules/)
As the error says: `Series.strides` are deprecated.
So how can I find the length of each `frozenset` in series? i.e. do same as above?

## MAIN ERROR

IMAGE 2

```
rules = (rules.groupby(['antecedants'])['consequents'])
```

After I evaluate above line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm         
2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 376, in 
evaluate_expression compiled = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
File "<string>", line 1
rules = (rules.groupby(['antecedants'])['consequents'])
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

-----WHY Syntax error, though works fine on JUPYTER NOTEBOOK?

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1159, in do_it
result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, 
self.expression, self.doExec)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 378, in 
evaluate_expression
Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\ProjcetPath\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6659, in groupby
observed=observed, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProjcetPath\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2152, in groupby
return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
File "C:\ProjcetPath\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 599, in __init__
mutated=self.mutated)
File "C:\ProjcetPath\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'antecedants'
```

--- At last it says key error, during handling `syntax` error `key` error occurred, For sure it is not key error as I can see column in `sciView`, also am able to access it this was as done in above code lines.

**OTHER INFO**: I am using `Django` as well.

Comment: How working change `rules["antecedant_len"] = rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: len(x))` to `rules["antecedant_len"] = rules["antecedents"].str.len()` ?

Comment: This one is for Deprecated `Series.strids`, all my code works great in Jupyter Notebook. But in pycharm it throws error, there are different errors at debug and at console, couldn't get error

Comment: For sanity purposes, please switch to using `antecedEnt` and versions of it instead of the (incorrect) `antecedAnt`.  If you mix it up it's hard to tell whether something is a typo or an intentional choice.

Comment: @AashishGahlawat - Hard question, I never seen before (maybe because use Anaconda, not pycharm)

Comment: @DSM coudn't get you sir!, I have just started with pandas.

Comment: @jezrael Sir I am using django to build apis for my project, and that whole is in pycharm itself more convenient.

Comment: This isn't about pandas. :-)  In your `rules['antecedants_length'] = rules['antecedents'].apply(lambda x: len(x))` line, you change your mind about the spelling.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for .str.len() it worked fine, and it was pycharm error only as it doesn't load dataframe itself to sciview unliess clicked on see as dataframe, other error was when dubugges, variable rules value changed on click of evalueate and then resulted into error

Comment: @DSM and @jazrael updated question sir, as error was with `pycharm` itself

Comment: Thanks @DSM it was a typo error only, english isn't my native so it wasn't an international choice. But came to know debug in pycharm brings variables to scope and running them again result different :)

Comment: It should be `anteceedEnt` rather than `antecedAnt` i.e. E in place of A, thats why I was getting key error